# Proof that in any set A such that A contains a circumference centered at zero you can't find a continuous square root function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, square-numbers

The following is an exercise in my textbook on complex analysis:

> Proof that in any set A such that A contains a circumference centered
> at zero you can't find a continuous square root function.

I'm trying to use to following definitions and theorems:

> A function $h:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is a square root in $\Omega$ if
> $h(z)^2=z$ $\forall z\in\Omega$.
>
> Theorem 1: Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ a non-empty and
> open set. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There are continuous arguments in $\Omega$.
> 2. There are continuous logarithms in $\Omega$.
> 3. There are holomorphic logarithms in $\Omega$.
> 4. The function $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ has a primitive function (antiderivative) in $\Omega$.
>
> Theorem 2: Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ non-empty
> containing a circumference centered at zero, then A hasn't got
> continuous arguments.

I'm not sure I need to use these but I believe some of ideas could be reused.

Comment: Your program is brave, but much too ambitious for the modest claim. In particular, the notion of "equivalent" concerning your four statements could lead to an impasse: It could be that for some reason there **is** a continuous square root, while there is no holomorphic logarithm.